# Assembly program to subtract three integers from user input(x-y-z)

Tags: assembly, x86, irvine32

Hello I am trying to write a program that subtracts three integers, (x-y-z) that the user enters and then output that to the screen. I believe I am on the right track but am lost on where to go next. I'm a beginner to assembly. This is irvine32 Assembly. Thank you!

```
TITLE Programming Assignment 1 (main.asm)

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
myMessage1 BYTE "Please input integer x: ",0dh,0ah,0
myMessage2 BYTE "Please input integer y: ",0dh,0ah,0
myMessage3 BYTE "Please input integer z: ",0dh,0ah,0
inputNum1 DWORD ?
inputNum2 DWORD ?
inputNum3 DWORD ?

.code
main PROC
   call Clrscr

   mov edx,offset myMessage1
   call WriteString
   call ReadInt
   mov inputNum1,eax


   mov edx,offset myMessage2
   call WriteString
   call ReadInt
   mov inputNum2,ebx

   mov edx,offset myMessage3
   call WriteString
   call ReadInt
   mov inputNum3,ecx

   sub eax, ebx
   sub ebx, ecx




   exit
   main ENDP

   END main
```

Answer (score 4):

`ReadInt` returns the number in `eax`. As such you should write that into your variables. To perform the arithmetic you then need to use said variables. Such as:

```
   mov edx,offset myMessage1
   call WriteString
   call ReadInt
   mov inputNum1,eax

   mov edx,offset myMessage2
   call WriteString
   call ReadInt
   mov inputNum2,eax

   mov edx,offset myMessage3
   call WriteString
   call ReadInt
   mov inputNum3,eax

   mov eax, inputNum1
   sub eax, inputNum2
   sub eax, inputNum3

   call WriteInt
```

PS: learn to use a debugger and read the documentation.

Comment: I particularly like the PS. <g>